# How to check in KeyListener that Ctrl was released?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I want to write keyReleased method which can check that Ctrl was released.

How to check that button is Ctrl in keyReleased handler?

Thanks friends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `KeyListener` on the component.

```
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL){
                // ctrl key is released
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Volodia, Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. This is why you are probably having problems with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23228448/131872

Comment: Thanks @camickr! Can you tell what to use as InputMap in JDialog. It doesn't have method getInputMap()?

Comment: JDialog doesn't have getActionMap() method.

Comment: I found it in your tutorial. I need to call getRootPane at first.

Comment: Can you also tell how to create KeyStroke for released Ctrl?

Comment: @Volodia, you use dialog.getRootPane() and add the Key Bindings to the root pane.