# How to make JTabbedPane not to catch Ctrl+Tab key binding?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

When I press `Ctrl`+`Tab`, selected tab in `JTabbedPane` receives focus.

But I want to remove this key binding. So I have my own action for key binding Ctrl+Tab. 
It is assigned to JTabbedPane.

But it's not fired because this key binding still focuses current tab.

Comment: Are you adding `KeyListener` on `JTabbedPane`? If yes then please share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have my own action for key binding Ctrl+Tab. It is assigned to JTabbedPane.

Did you use the proper InputMap when you assigned the Key Binding. Most LAF's will use the `JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` InputMap.

See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of the bindings for your LAF.

If the Key Binding don't work then another option might be to remove Ctrl-Tab as a focus traversal key from your tabbed pane:

```
Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet();
newForwardKeys.add( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB") );
tabbedPane.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newForwardKeys);
```